# If returns always true and check each element with has()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On input focus, I want to check if the msg class does not have an err class with it, then do something. I tried it with the following code, but the if-statement always returns true.

**jQuery**

```
$('form .field input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    if($(this).parent().find('.msg').parent().not(':has(.err)')) {
        $(this).parent().find('.msg').parent().stop()[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']();
    }
})
```

Then I want to also check every msg class which have the err class also with it. And if there is only 1 I want to select the input in the parent.

This is my attempt but it didn't work.

```
if($('.msg').parent('.field').has('.err').length === 1) {
    $(this).parents().find('input').select();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text">
    <div>
        <div class="msg">Msg.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="text">
    <div>
        <div class="msg err">Err msg.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) doesn't return a boolean like [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is). It's the opposite of [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter). The collection returned is always evaluated as truthy.

```
if ($(this).parent().find('.msg').parent().not(':has(.err)')) {
```

should probably be:

```
if (!$(this).parent().find('.msg').parent().is(':has(.err)')) {
//  ^ not                                   ^^ returns boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$('form .field input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    if(!$(this).parent().find('.msg').parent().hasClass('err')) {
        $(this).parent().find('.msg').parent().stop()[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']();
    }
})

if($('.msg').parent('.field').hasClass('err')) {
    $(this).parents().find('input').select();
}
```